# Using variables and simple calculation with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am not familiar with CSS. When setting style for various elements, is there a clean way to set the dimensions of the elements that depend on each others? In the example below, suppose that I need to change the height of either container2 or container3 and  keep their total height to be the same as that of container 1, I have to go though the css file and modify their heights manually one by one keeping in mind this summation constraint. For eg, if I have to change the height of container2 to be 100px, I have to change that of container3 to 400px, so as to maintain a sum of 500px. This situation get messier when there are more elements whose dimensions depend on each other. Is there a way to make such changes dynamic?

For eg, can we do something like: set two variables to be `height2` and `heigh3` and set a constraint `height2 + height3 = 500px`. So that if either `height2` or `height3` is changed, some simple calculation can be executed to maintain the 500px constraint?

```css
#container1 {
    height: 30%;
    width: 300px;
    }

#container2 {
    height: 70%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    }
    
 #container3 {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container1">
   <div id="container2">        
   </div>
   <div id="container3">    
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just use percentage heights?

Comment: You can use a preprocessor such as SASS, or CSS variables. Check the comparison here https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example of using CSS vars. You can find more info here https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/

```css
:root {
  --main-width: 300px;
  --height-one: 200px;
  --height-two: 300px;
}

#container1 {
  background: red;
  /* 60px just to show it works, because you don't need to set height anyway here */
  height: calc(var(--height-one) + var(--height-two) + 60px);
  width: var(--main-width);
}

#container2 {
  height: var(--height-one);
  width: var(--main-width);
  background-color: blue;
}
    
 #container3 {
   height: var(--height-two);
   width: var(--main-width);
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="container2"></div>
  <div id="container3"></div>
</div>
```

But what you should really do is use percentages, as Paulie_D has suggested in comments.

```css
#container1 {
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
}

#container2 {
  height: 40%;
  background-color: blue;
}
    
 #container3 {
   height: 60%;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
   <div id="container2">        
   </div>
   <div id="container3">    
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on ```var```. I will check this out. I have used percentage. However, if the div is not populated with any elements (which are to be created dynamically in my app), its dimensions seem to collapse, unless set with ```px```.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but you can set the parent element to have `px` values, and then children elements would use `%` percentage of that value, then it shouldn't collapse?

Answer (score 2):

In your particular example, if main container need to adjust the heights of children, you just not need to set its height, it will have its content height by default, and once you set main container height, child div will have 100% width by default.

In general, there is a way to use variables in css using `--name` notation. and simplee calculations using `calc` function. like this:

```css
:root { /*define variables*/
  --w: 300px;
  --h1: 200px;
  --h2: 300px;
}
#container1 {
    height: calc(var(--h1) + var(--h2)); /* css calculation */
    width: var(--w); /* simple use of variable*/
    }

#container2 {
    height: var(--h1);
    width: var(--w);
    background-color: blue;
    }
    
 #container3 {
    height: var(--h2);
    width: var(--w);
    background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container1">
   <div id="container2">        
   </div>
   <div id="container3">    
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am going with @dw_'s since his is similar.